# SQL Server 2005 WHERE Clause with like condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need to build a `WHERE` clause based on the parameter that is been passed into a stored procedure.

For example: if `param1` value is 1 then do like condition,

```
 @param1 like '%'+ product.Status + '%'
```

else I want to ignore the like condition and it would return all rows....

How would I do it in the `WHERE` clause? Thanks,

Comment: Is this in C#/VB code or in pure TSQL?

Comment: its pure TSQL, It is a store procedure.

Comment: How can param1 both be equal to 1 and be like `'%'+ product.Status + '%'`?

Comment: You want a wildcard match on the product.Status column?

Comment: @Ben can you please clarify your Where Clause? The current one isn't really clear what it does.

Comment: param1 is the expected parameter in the sp. and I want if/case condition to check if it is value 1 then do a like condition to retrieve all possible records, if its not 1, ignore the like condition, I hope it makes sense what I am doing...

Comment: @Ben, that could only result in getting all rows or all rows where product.Status = 1

Comment: It's a store**D** procedure - as in **STORED** inside SQL Server. It has nothing to do with a "store" of any kind....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO you need to alter the where clause depending on a parameter. Use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188001.aspx): you can build the query as a string, so you can add the where clause if @param = 1:

```
declare @sql varchar(1024)
declare @where varchar(1024)
set @sql = N'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable'
set @where = N' WHERE columnName like '%'+ product.Status + '%''
case when @param = 1 then concat(@sql,@where)
execute sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

@param1 like ISNULL('%'+ product.Status + '%', '%')

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `IF` Condition. Try something like this.

```
if @param1 = 1
    Begin
        select * from tableName WHERE columnName like '%'+ product.Status + '%' 
    End
else
    Begin
        select * from tableName WHERE columnName
    End
```

Comment: can I just do the where clause in the if condition? I dont want the select to be duplicated many times...

Comment: I think no, you can use InLine `IF` and `Case` for specified condition of the column only.

Answer (score 0):

My guess from your description (not code) is that you want a query like the following:

```
select *
from product
where ([Status] like '%' + @param1 + '%'
    or @param1 is null)
```

This will return all products that wildcard-match Status on @param1 or return all rows if @param1 is null.

I've used parenthesis in the event that you add more to your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The `like` operator needs two parameters:

```
where ( @Param1 = 1 and product.Status like '%' + @Pattern + '%' ) or
  ( @Param1 = 2 and product.Voltage = 240 ) or
  ( @Param1 is NULL )
```